# Set the labels between xticks

Tags: matlab, plot, label

I want to put labels between ticks, otherwise some labels overlap each other.

```
set(gca,'XTick',[66 98 134 215 266 330 334 388 414 443 ]);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'CD', 'CS', 'E' ,'F','H','I','C','IT','M','U'})
```

[image]

Could somebody please help me?

Comment: Thanks for editing. There 'C' overlaps 'I'.

Comment: Have you considered expanding the size of your figure?

Answer (score 0):

```
xTICKS = [66 98 134 215 266 330 334 388 414 443 ];
xTICKS = [0 xTICKS]; %// Add the 0 instance
dxT = diff(xTICKS);%// get differences
xT = xTICKS(1:end-1)+dxT/2; %// Make new tick locations midway the old
```

This way you can create the locations of your tickmarks + ticklabels midway the old instances. I'm not sure whether you can uncouple the two though, try this:

```
set(gca,'XTick',xT);
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'CD', 'CS', 'E' ,'F','H','I','C','IT','M','U'})
```

You can play around with [axes properties](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html), especially those in the section *tick values and labels*, but I can't see a way to uncouple the tick location and it's corresponding label.

Comment: Thanks, but this method changes the tick location, too.

Comment: @user5254599 yes, that is exactly what I said *I can't see a way to uncouple the tick location and it's corresponding label* meaning, I do not think there is a way to do this, other than what I showed. I'll check whether it's possible to plot "two axes", one with labels and no ticks and one with ticks and no labels, but I do not have high hopes for that.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this problem frequently, but there is a very simple solution...simply pad your labels with spaces on the front!  Not necessarily all of them...just the ones that need to move.  This is a great trick any time you need a minor adjustment in a text annotation (like with 'arrow', 'text', etc.)

Example:

```
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'CD', 'CS', 'E' ,'F','H','I','  C','IT','M','U'})
```

EDIT: 
I realized this doesn't address the vertical tick problem.  For the Y axis, try

```
set(gca,'YTickLabel',{'CD', 'CS', 'E' ,'F','H','I',['A' char(10) ' C'],'IT','M','U'})
```

Note that 'A' and 'C' are technically part of the same label, but they appear to be two different labels because of inserting a line feed (char(10)).