# Show xticks which are function of x-axis, not directly the data it self. Example with dates (pandas, matplotlib)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization, seaborn

While working with seaborn, I tried to set x-ticks to be different from my data unsuccessfully. I'll give concrete example in a moment, but I also generalized my question. If there is a canonical answer to the general question that will be great.

Is it possible to set x-ticks to be a function of the data what I used for plotting? When I can't plot function of data directly.

1. Assume I've a method which receive `x` and returns `f(x)`. Is it possible to plot data by `x`, but showing `f(x)` in x axis? Like returning a string for each number, and I want to show the string.
2. If I have a dataframe which I plot as x-axis his column name "col_x", and I want instead of that x-ticks to show data of "col_f_x". Can I make somehow a "match" between two columns?

Questions are similar of course, while the first assumes I have a function, the second asks directly about two columns in dataframe.

Now for concrete example. My initial goal was to use `seaborn.displot` on dates. Unfortunately, it seems it does not support working with dates. I decided to do some bypass and plot data by days difference. I explained what I did here: [How to plot Pandas datetime series in Seaborn distplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38567358/how-to-plot-pandas-datetime-series-in-seaborn-distplot/62232217)
, that is the origin of my question.

Let's use this simple example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

original_dates = ["2016-03-05", "2017-03-05", "2016-02-05", "2016-02-05", "2016-02-05", "2015-03-05"]
dates_list = [dt.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d').date() for date in original_dates]

df = pd.DataFrame({"Date":dates_list})

df["NewDate"] = df["Date"] - dt.date(2015,3,5)
df["NewDate"] = df["NewDate"].apply(lambda x: x.days)

import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
ax = sns.distplot(df['NewDate'])
```

Output:

[image: displot with days instead of dates]

I used numerical different of days instead of plotting Date column directly. But I want my xticks to be dates, not numerical difference. How can I do this?

I hope my two general questions are now more clearer: I can supply to the plot a function (date - starting_date) or different column (Date), by I'm still not sure how to set x-ticks accordingly.

During my small research on that I tackled across matplotlib's `major_locator` and `major_formatter`. I guess I suppose to use them, but couldn't figure out how to do it on my own. Some of related posts in stack overflow I found during my search:

[Manipulating Dates in x-axis Pandas Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42727853/manipulating-dates-in-x-axis-pandas-matplotlib)

[Set the labels between xticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33569552/set-the-labels-between-xticks)

[matplotlib set xticks to column, labels to corresponding index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43717739/matplotlib-set-xticks-to-column-labels-to-corresponding-index)

[plot_date function set xticks for hourly data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52729169/plot-date-function-set-xticks-for-hourly-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following at the end of your code

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def my_func(x):
    return dt.date(2015,3,5) + dt.timedelta(days=x)

ticks = plt.xticks()[0]
dates = [my_func(x) for x in ticks]
plt.xticks(ticks, dates)
```

Comment: thank you, it works almost perfect (just need to adjust space between labels). To generalize your answer, I can always use `plt.xticks(ticks, my_func)` where `my_func` is a result of ticks I want?

Comment: Yes, I edited the answer to be in that form. You can also change the last line to `plt.xticks(ticks, dates, rotation=45)` to rotate the labels so they might fit better.